# Story about a boy who travels through time by turning a cradle to save a baby

Tags: story-identification

I am trying to figure out the name of this children's book where a boy travels through time to the past and becomes friends with this girl and saves her baby brother from a disease by giving him yellow pills and almost ends up dying of the disease instead. He travelled by twisting a knob on a cradle or something similar

Comment: Probably not a lot of help, but the yellow color of the pill makes me wonder if they're thinking of sulfa drugs, early antibiotics